# Get top 10 values from log file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sh

I have to create a report by reading a huge log file.

The log file contains data something like this.

REQUEST     Call set up for X5356E08XWZV0ZVAE1  1645167707895   1645167709644   OK
REQUEST     Call to database : X5356E08XWZV0ZVAE2   1645167709651   1645167709748   OK
REQUEST     Call set up for X5356E08XWZV0ZVAE3  1645167709750   1645167709874   OK
REQUEST     Set Mau Preparation for X5356E08XWZV0ZVAE4  1645167709875   1645167709991   OK
REQUEST     Call track key end point for X5356E08XWZV0ZVAE5 1645167709992   1645167710379   KO

Now, I need to write a shell script. If First column is REQUEST, then subtract NF-2 from NF-1 and print top 3 USERS. If the line contains KO, ignore that line.

I am trying to build a simple logic awk but not much success. Any help greatly appreciated.
I tried below code but it just sorts the time but I need to print user name too if the first column is REQUEST.

```
awk '$1 == "REQUEST" {print $(NF-3)" "  $(NF-1) - $(NF-2)}' "path/simulation_1.log"
```

I got response
USER1 1000
USER2 2000
.
.
I want the reponse to be sorted descending and only 10 entries.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] with concise, testable, textual sample input and expected output formatted as code blocks (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). There should be no ellipses or anything else that doesn't exist in your real data in your example - we need something we can copy/paste to test with. Make the example about printing, say, the top 3 users instead of top 10 so you don't have to provide a lot of text for your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN {printf "Top ten User are\n"} {if ($0 !~ "KO" && $1 == "REQUEST") {print $2" time taken "$3-$4" seconds" | "sort -nrk4 | head -n10 "}}'
```

Comment: Just one condition, The line shouldnt contain column with "KO" as string. If "KO" is there, it should ignore.

Comment: added skipping and made it one liner

Comment: `printf "foo\n"` is best written as just `print "foo"` so it uses the value of ORS instead of hard-coding the value that you hope/assume ORS will have.